# Parsing SOAP XML with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xml-serialization, legacy

I work with legacy system (not my design) and it have some data persisted in db as serialized xml (SOAP).

XML was created with SoapFormatter.

```
SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
```

I can't simply deserialize from SOAP because of versioning problem. Model from which data were created have changed and deserialization of persisted data (in xml) is not possible. So I'm trying to figure out how to manually "deserialize" old SOAP to existing model.

I can load it into XDocument and then extract node values with LINQ. But I have problem with Guid values. They are stored in in SOAP XML like this:

```
<someId xsi:type="a2:Guid" xmlns:a2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/ns/System">
                <_a>1396006029</_a>
                <_b>2720</_b>
                <_c>20328</_c>
                <_d>162</_d>
                <_e>217</_e>
                <_f>181</_f>
                <_g>57</_g>
                <_h>113</_h>
                <_i>92</_i>
                <_j>64</_j>
                <_k>35</_k>
            </someId>
```

Is there any way to do it painless?

I can read them one by one like this:

```
var someId = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "root").Elements("someId").Elements("_a").Value;
```

and try to parse to Guid but it doesn't look nice.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
I added <Root xmlns:xsi="abc"> to xml because the xsi namespace wan't defined.
```

Try code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication28
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement someId = doc.Descendants("someId").FirstOrDefault();

            dict = someId.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (int)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());


        }
    }
}
```